# Help With Difficult Integration

Tags: integration, physics, classical-mechanics

I'm working through a homework problem and came to the point where I needed to evaluate this integral.

$$\int_{-(z^2 - 2z)}^{z^2 - 2z}    \dfrac{-1}{\alpha z} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ \dfrac{2}{m} \bigg (E - z^2 - 2z - \dfrac{l^2 \alpha^2}{2m(\ln(z))^2} \bigg )} } dz$$

I'll give some background on the problem quickly. I'm trying to find the equation of motion of a particle of mass $m$ in the 1D Morse potential, 
$$V(x) = D \big ( e^{-2\alpha x} - 2e^{-\alpha x} \big ).$$
In consulting with my professor, he gave me the hint of setting  $z = e^{-\alpha x}$ and solving for $x$. This gives $x = -\frac{1}{\alpha}\ln(z)$. He then suggested I use an equation from Goldstein's Classical Mechanics, which was
$$ t = \int_{r_0}^r \dfrac{dr}{\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{m}\big ( E - V - \dfrac{l^2}{2mr^2} \big )}}$$

I did as he suggesting using $r=x$. I chose my integration bounds to be the turning points of the potential, $E = \pm V(x) = \pm(z^2 -2z)$. Now I'm stuck with this seemingly horrendous integral that I don't know how to solve. Once I get this, it's a simple matter of inverting that equation from $t(x)$ to $x(t)$ to get my equation of motion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: This comment could be a big help (because it will get rid of a horrendous term in the denominator of the integrand) or it might be flat out wrong. Vaguely from memory, the equation you wrote down has an $\ell ^2/2mr^2$ term, which is some type of weird angular momentum/centrifugal term. If your problem is truly 1-dimensional, then there should be no angular momentum term. If the particle can only move up and down along a line, you can't associate angular momentum with this movement. The equation you copied down most likely came from a section talking about a 2-body system that's free to move

Comment: in 3-dimensions. The equation that you wrote down is for 2-body systems in 3-dimensions, which have a really nice interparticle conservative force acting between them that allows the math to turn into something that looks 1-dimensional. The equation that you need is that same equation, but just drop the $\ell ^2/2mr^2$ term. This makes the integrand a little easier

Comment: @DWade64, I was actually just thinking about that. I'd just say $l = 0$ and have the denominator as $\sqrt{\frac{2}{m} (E- z^2 + 2z)}$, yeah?

Comment: Yeah, and why do you have a $\alpha z$ in the denominator as well? Using the equation, you should integrate from a starting $z_0$ to a final $z$?

Comment: @DWade64 The $\alpha z$ in the denominator was when I took $dz$ $x = -ln(z) / \alpha$ which gives $dz = -1/(\alpha z)$.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your integral, like how $z$ is both present as the dummy variable and in the limit of integration. If I understand correctly, $z$ is real, so how can you integrate something with $\ln z$ over a negative domain? So instead, I'll address the modified integral from the comments. We need
$$ \int_{-(z^2-2z)}^{(z^2-2z)}\frac{1}{\alpha t\sqrt{\frac2m(E-t^2+2t)}}dt. $$
Notice that the argument of the square root in the denominator can be expressed as $(\frac{2E}m+1)-(t-1)^2$, allowing an easy trigonometric substitution to complete the integral. Then, just integrate your resulting integral just like you typically would in an elementary calculus course. (I have a feeling that you got your signs wrong somewhere, since the limits of integration do not work out nicely at all, but since I'm not acquainted with the physics of the problem I can't say for certain. Either way, this is probably the best method.)